# Snap.svg - Inconsistent SVG Rendering between Chrome / Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

I'm working with animated SVGs / Snap.svg for the first time, so please forgive my lack of knowledge on this subject.

I made a series of 3 animated SVG "frames" (400x300px), each nested within a larger SVG (1200x300px) to contain them all. A `div` element with a `clip` style property hides the other two "frames" when they're not ready to be shown.

Using Snap.svg, each frame is supposed to "slide" into view using `translate` after a certain amount of time, and within each frame are some animated elements.

Long story short: the animation looks perfect in Firefox, but it looks awful in Chrome/Webkit. In Chrome, it looks like each of the frames are just being stacked on top of each other instead of side-by-side.

In addition, two of the elements (the cow circle `joules` and the graph circle `graph`) are rendering in the upper-left corner instead of using their `translate` property to position them in the center-right area.

You can see the animation in Plunker. Please try it out in both browsers to see what I mean.

http://plnkr.co/UhTy83

Firefox GIF screen capture:

[image]

Chrome GIF screen capture:

[image]

Comment: I would break it down into smaller code with less examples. First guess is that you are applying a transform to svg element. Transforms on svg tag isn't really supported, so append the svg elements into a group and transform the group instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ian! Swapping out the `<svg>` tags for `<g>` (group) tags fixed this problem. It's interesting to me that Firefox allows you to transform `<svg>` elements but Webkit does not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ian in the comments to my question! Swapping out the `<svg>` tags for `<g>` (group) tags fixed this problem. It's interesting to me that Firefox allows you to transform `<svg>` elements but Webkit does not.

Before:

```
<svg class="slides" width="1200" height="300">
    <svg class="slide1" width="400" height="300"></svg>
    <svg class="slide2" width="400" height="300"></svg>
    <svg class="slide3" width="400" height="300"></svg>
</svg>
```

After:

```
<svg class="slides" width="1200" height="300">
    <g class="slide1"></g>
    <g class="slide2"></g>
    <g class="slide3"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Transform on SVG elements is a new feature in the upcoming draft SVG 2 specification (it's not allowed in SVG 1.1) Chrome and Firefox have implemented some parts of SVG 2, this is one part that Firefox has implemented that Chrome has not. There are other parts implemented in both and some only in Chrome as yet.